# coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert causes an error: NameError: name '_tree' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, python-2.x, coremltools

TLDR: I can't convert my linear regression model into a model I can save like below:

```
model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(regr, input_features, output_feature)
model.save("Advertising.mlmodel")
```

I was working on a Raywenderlich tutorial [Beginning Machine Learning with SciKit Learn](https://www.raywenderlich.com/174-beginning-machine-learning-with-scikit-learn#toc-anchor-005) and I stumbled upon an error at the end of Jupyter Notebook when I convert my linear regression to a model I can save, it gives me the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-da16b7baefa4> in <module>
     12 # tree.export_graphviz(model)
     13 
---> 14 coreml_model = coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert(model, inputs, output)
     15 coreml_model.save('Advertising.mlmodel')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/sklearn/_converter.py in convert(sk_obj, input_features, output_feature_names)
    146     # several issues with the ordering of the classes are worked out.  For now,
    147     # to use custom class labels, directly import the internal function below.
--> 148     from ._converter_internal import _convert_sklearn_model
    149 
    150     spec = _convert_sklearn_model(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/sklearn/_converter_internal.py in <module>
     34 from . import _LinearSVR
     35 from . import _linear_regression
---> 36 from . import _decision_tree_classifier
     37 from . import _decision_tree_regressor
     38 from . import _gradient_boosting_classifier

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/sklearn/_decision_tree_classifier.py in <module>
     14 
     15 model_type = "classifier"
---> 16 sklearn_class = _tree.DecisionTreeClassifier
     17 
     18 

NameError: name '_tree' is not defined
```

It's weird because according to Apple's official documentation at [github.io/coremltools](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.sklearn.convert.html), their implementation is the same as Raywenderlich and still doesnt work for me.

Here is the link to my [notebook](http://localhost:8888/notebooks/SUP2.1/Week1-Beginning%20Machine%20Learning%20with%20scikit-learn/Advertisement%20Notebook.ipynb)

Answer (score 2):

CoreMlTools is suited for scikit-learn version of 19.2 and below.
Probably you have the greater version.

Try to downgrade scikit-learn to 19.2 this way:

```
!pip install --force-reinstall 'scikit-learn==0.19.2'
```